# sqlite, c++, disconnect after task?

Tags: c++, sqlite, sqlcipher

New to sqlite, I come from the web development where connect do a task and disconnect is the proper way to use a db. Now im using sqlite for a c++ software, locally. No interet and no servers.

Could / should I keep the connection open untill I close the program to speed up the app ? (Im using an encrypted db, sqlcipher)

**edit:**

To keep it open, i have 2 possible problem:

1 securit. but in this case the security could even improve having a lock on the file(?). Or there could be an unencrypted copy of the file (temp file) somewhere ?

2 efficency: if the file is open i dont do the connect/disconnect but could let a process open, for sure this process is not intensive but... i have to see...

Comment: Are you constantly using the database, or are you using it sparingly?

Comment: sqlite is a local database.  You're not sharing it with other applications, are you?  Or other instances of your same applications?  If the answer to both of those questions is "no" then keep it open for as long as you like

Comment: @tas its very variable but i'd say sparingly.
@ joe No i dont share it.

Comment: @Joe ..........

Comment: @Tas ..........

Answer (score 2):

Connecting to a database is an expensive operation. For that reason, even in Web development, it is common to use a connection pool: you have a number of available connections, and each transaction takes a connection from the pool, does its job and returns the connection to the pool.

But with that design, it is also common to regularly *recycle* connections by closing and reopening them. The rationale is that if a portion of code does not behave correctly and for example forgets to release a resource, closing the connection will ensure a proper cleaning.

In your local system it is not that different: using a new connection for every task will certainly be a waste of resources, but if the program can live a long time, never recycling the connection assumes that all database accesses are perfectly correct, which can be brave...

No doubt that **you** are very cautious about it, but what if somebody else has to later maintain that code... ;-)

Long story made short the lifetime of the connection is a balance between performance (longer is better) and robustness (shorter is better)